# Dynamic DNS advice for a home server on a .co.uk domain

Tags: networking, server, dns, router, dynamic-ip

I have the following setup:

- A home server running Ubuntu Server 12.04
- A D-Link DSL-2780 capable of Dynamic DNS routing to www.dyndns.org, www.no-ip.com, zoneedit.com
- A domain purchased with Gandi.com which does not run a dynamic dns service but does have 'DNS Zones'

I've done a bit of reading about how to connect my IP - and thus presumably my home server - to my pre-purchased domain name. Some suggest [installing](http://perceptionistruth.com/2013/05/running-your-own-dynamic-dns-service-on-debian/) a [custom](http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=7734) [script](http://code.google.com/p/gandi-automatic-dns/) which will communicate with the gandi zone files via the API and auto update. [Others](http://lifehacker.com/124804/geek-to-live--how-to-assign-a-domain-name-to-your-home-web-server) (possibly out of date) suggest using a free service provided by dynDNS or no-ip.

- I'm retisant to install any more code on my server than I have to in the spirit of trying to be secure whilst I learn as much as I can about what every line does. So preferably an external service would be good (correct me if I'm being stupid here).
- I can't seem to find a 'free Dynamic DNS service' that applies to me in the way these guides state. Perhaps I am confused but no-ip.com but as my domain ends in `.co.uk` I only seem to be able to use the paid for services (which I don't object to but would then prefer to start shopping around).

Might someone let me know if times have moved on and free services for `.co.uk` are currently not available, or if I'm likely misunderstanding something about managing hosts / domains.

I then assume once i've resolved this it should be as simple as pointing my router to my DNS account, which in turn will point to my gandi-domain, thus allowing me to get to my home server via my domain name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free dynamic DNS services seem to be disappearing, so be prepared to pay for the service. This is still less expensive in most cases than securing a static IP address from your ISP.

Regardless of who you choose for service from any of the dynamic DNS service providers, they should be able to provide service for a `.co.uk` domain. They will provide a list of nameservers that you then enter into the nameserver settings in your gandi.com domain account settings. Then follow the instructions from the dynamic DNS provider for setting up your DNS records with them. In your router, enter the account info for your dynamic DNS account. If and when your router IP address changes, it will notify your dynamic DNS provider of the change, who will in turn update your DNS A Records with the new router IP.

This is exactly the setup that I have used for my home server using dyn.com (formerly dyndns.org) and it works with no problems.

Comment: Thanks douggro, that's really helpful. Out of interest, any reason why you went with dyn.com over no-ip.com for your setup?

Comment: @Huw No particular reason for going with dyn.com.